# fsolve and fimplicit for a non-linear equation

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, digamma-function

It's well known that from time to time nonlinear solver fsolve in Matlab gives controversial results  but I'd like to ask and simultaneously share my experience of the exploitation of this command.
I want to solve nonlinear equation and find a function $y=y(x)$

$-\Psi(1/2) +{\it \Re} \left( \Psi \left( 1/2+{
\frac { \left( 1+i \right) \tau\,\tanh \left(  \left( 1+i \right) x
 \right) }{y}} \right)  \right) +\ln  \left( y \right) =0$

where $\Psi(z)$ is the digamma function of a complex argument and $\tau$ is a real positive number.
Here is my code in Matlab:

```
function z=temperature
dd=linspace(0,5,1000);
for j=1:1000
 if j==1
        x0=1;
    else
    x0=temp(j-1);
 end
z1=fsolve(@(y) self(y,dd(j)),x0,optimset('Display','off'));
temp(j)=z1;
end
plot(dd,temp,'Color','black','LineWidth',3);
function z=self(y,x)
tau=1/(10.05);
z=-psin(1/2)+real(psin(1/2+(1+1i)*tau*tanh((1+1i)*x)/y))+log(y);
end
end
```

Here  psin(n,z) for the calculation of the polygamma function for a complex argument can be found [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5687-polygamma-function-of-arbitrary-order-valid-complex-plane?focused=5060922&tab=function) on Matlab central.

Matlab gives the answer

[image]

Meanwhile I can do almost the same with another command fimplicit again in Matlab wit the very simple code

```
tau=1/(10.05); 
z=@(x,y) -psin(1/2)+real(psin(1/2+(1+1i)*tau*tanh((1+1i)*x)./y))+log(y);
fimplicit(z,[0 5 0 1.1])
```

and obtain now correct plot (see below)

[image]

I know about that the solution strongly depends on the initial point for fsolve. But I checked a lot of initial values and I didn't obtain this figure.
Btw fsolve in *Maple* solves this nonlinear equation correctly.

**How I can improve my code in Matlab with fsolve to reproduce the last figure? Any suggestions?**

Comment: For Matlab it is the same $\log$ and $\ln$?

Comment: Yes, it is. log and ln are the same